# Control in placed where UITabBar should be does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl that is placed where a UITabBar is normally visible. When I hide the UITabBar, so the control is visible, the UISegmentedControl does not respond to touches. I have tried disabling user interaction for the UITabBar, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling - (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view; with your UISegmentedControl when you hide your UITabBar.

eg:
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:segmentedControl];

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work! If I move move the UISegmentedControl up above where the UITabBar would be, it works as expected...